# ERC20 - Bad overwrite of _beforeTokenTransfer() hook

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I was reading that its posible to use hooks on ERC20 to implement new functionality without touch the original code.

In this case im worried about why its necessary to add super call when you redefine a hook (ex beforeTokenTransfer)

```
super._beforeTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);
```

https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/erc20-with-safety-rails/

There are any security issues if i implement something like this?:

```
contract MyCoin is ERC20 {
....
....
function _beforeTokenTransfer( address from, address to, uint256 amount ) internal virtual override { 
  if(.......){
     revert("....")
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no security risk, `_beforeTokenTransfer` should be used to extend the contract and add limitations.

You should add the super call because it's stated [here](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/erc20-with-safety-rails/) that:

> Even though currently ERC20._beforeTokenTransfer doesn't do anything, we call it in case functionality is added in the future.